# Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis - can you help figure out issue

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select regexp_substr((replace(replace(replace(('CA','CO','IL','KS'),chr(40)),chr(41)), chr(39))), '[^,]+', 1, level) as division from dual
                                   connect by level <= regexp_count(('CA','CO','IL','KS'), '[,]') + 1;
```

ERROR:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Can you help me figure out why this is erroring out.

EDIT - I cannot manipulate the string to have extra quotes in there. This is a fixed format i get from a table. How can i strip it to get a row format output?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Regexp functions take strings as input, not lists as you are trying here.

Comment: Hi @GMB, I will get this static output ('CA','CO','IL','KS') froma dynamic variable from loop. I want to strip it to get all the values in a row format. How can i do it?

Comment: Then I think that Barbaros Özhan's answer does what you want.

Comment: I cannot go and change the strings to have extra quotes. I will  get this string as is in my question. My task is to strip that to get rows. How can i do that?

Comment: @user:5841306 are you able to help?

Answer (score 1):

You have a quotation problem(*quote the whole term `('CA','CO','IL','KS')` after adding extra quotes per each single quote*), try this rather :

```
 SELECT regexp_substr((replace(replace(replace('(''CA'',''CO'',''IL'',''KS'')',
                      chr(40)),
                      chr(41)), 
                      chr(39))), '[^,]+', 1, level) AS division 
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count('(''CA'',''CO'',''IL'',''KS'')', ',') + 1;

DIVISION
--------
CA
CO
IL
KS
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3e9111502cb3fe1546f10ae788b6d777)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros. The ('CA','CO','IL','KS') output i am getting is fixed. This is what i get from a dynamic variable in a loop. I want to strip the values in a row format. How can i do it?

Comment: How can i make it work if my string is fixed ('CA','CO','IL','KS') and i am not able to manipulate it to get extra quotes. This string is a stored value in a table and will be the same format.